# pandas DataFrame print index value only once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
li = [{"employee_id":1,"project_handled": "pas"},{"employee_id":1,"project_handled": "asap"},{"employee_id":2,"project_handled": "trimm"},{"employee_id":2,"project_handled": "fat"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(li)
df.set_index("employee_id",inplace=True)
print(df)
```

gives:

```
            project_handled
employee_id                
1                       pas
1                      asap
2                     trimm
2                       fat
```

What I want is, index values shouldn't be repeated when printing:

```
            project_handled
employee_id                
1                       pas
                       asap
2                     trimm
                        fat
```

I want to serialise this and share as excel using DataFrame.to_excel api. And the requirement is index shouldn't repeat itself in the employee_id column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `MultiIndex`:

```
import pandas as pd
li = [{"employee_id":1,"project_handled": "pas"},{"employee_id":1,"project_handled": "asap"},{"employee_id":2,"project_handled": "trimm"},{"employee_id":2,"project_handled": "fat"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(li)
df['Something'] = 1
df.set_index(["employee_id", "project_handled"],inplace=True)
print(df)
```

I've added `Something` because otherwise you'd get:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(1, pas), (1, asap), (2, trimm), (2, fat)]
```

**EDIT**

To create it without `project_handled` you'd need empty column and `MultiIndex`:

```
df["another"] = ""
df.set_index(["employee_id", "another"],inplace=True)
```

Comment: But aren't you abusing multi index? I don't want an index on project handled... I just want the first index to be printed only once.... The data I have given here is toy data... my use case is more complex....

Comment: If you want to _see_ the data like this, you will have to go with `MultiIndex`. Another way without involving `project_handled` is in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to print your `DataFrame` to a csv in the required fashion and you don't need to have only one cell for each `employee_id` value then you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

li = [{"employee_id":1,"project_handled": "pas"},{"employee_id":1,"project_handled": "asap"},{"employee_id":2,"project_handled": "trimm"},{"employee_id":2,"project_handled": "fat"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(li)

def custom_func(x): 
    for i in range(1, x['employee_id'].size):
            x['employee_id'].iloc[i] = ''
    return x;

df['employee_id'] = df['employee_id'].apply(str)
df = df.groupby('employee_id').apply(custom_func).set_index('employee_id')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            project_handled
employee_id
1                       pas
                       asap
2                     trimm
                        fat
```

The result of `df.to_csv('test.csv')` looks like:

[image]